Prove an equation given the system of symmetrical equations
Given is the following: 
Real numbers $a, b, c, d, e, f$ satisfy the following equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a^2+2bc=d^2+2ef \\ 
b^2+2ac=e^2+2df \\ 
c^2+2ab=f^2+2de
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
Prove that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = d^2 + e^2 + f^2$
So far my progress with this question was reaching the conclusion that $(a+b+c)^2 = (d+e+f)^2$. If you sum the equations together, you'll get: $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2bc + 2ac + 2ab = d^2 + e^2 + f^2 + 2ef + 2df + 2de$$
Which would also mean that to prove the given equation: $$2bc + 2ac + 2ab = 2ef + 2df + 2de$$
My issue is that by doing any sorts of substitutions I keep circling back to $(a+b+c)^2 = (d+e+f)^2$, and I have no idea how to tackle the problem in any other way.

As you have said, we have $(a+b+c)^2=(d+e+f)^2$.
Since $x^2=y^2$ implies $(x-y)(x+y)=0$, and hence $x=y$ or $x=-y$ we have either $a+b+c=d+e+f$ or $a+b+c=-d-e-f$. In the first case we obtain, solving the equations, and using that $x^2+y^2=0$ implies $x=y=0$, that
\begin{align}
f & = a + b + c - d - e,\\
c & = (- a + d + 2e)/2,\\
b & = a + d - e,
\end{align}
which gives indeed $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2+e^2+f^2$. The second case is similar.

Can you elaborate on how you solved the equations?

@CalvinLin I start with $f=a+b+c-d-e$ and substitute this, and then $b$ can be eliminated from the first equation (it only appears in linear terms). The third equation then gives $(a + 2c - d - 2e)(a - d)p=0$, where $p$ is a polynomial in $a,c,d,e$. The case $p=0$ gives a contradiction (or only complex solutions), so I obtain $d=a$, or $a+2c-d-2e=0$. The case $d=a$ gives $c=e$ and $f=b$, so is trivially true.

@CalvinLin Of course I know that this is not the solution we want. It only shows that it is possible to do it this way.
